# How to set table in HTML and have border move with zoom out

Tags: html, css, web, html-table, border

My problem is a simple one that I cannot figure out.

I want a table with the whole page being a cell, and when zooming out on a browser, I want the table border to get bigger/zoom out whatever works as long as the cell stays the same size.

Edit:

```
<table style="height:100%;width:100%; position: absolute; top: 0; 
bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;border:50px solid">

</table>
```

I have tried the above but the site moves around with different zoom levels. Also to better word my question, I am trying to get a border to act as a background around the whole page, which i want to stay a fit size regardless of zoom level.

Comment: Why do you want to use a table for that? Its way out of its purpose. Much easier to use flexbox with a fixed size and center it vertically and horizontally

Comment: You need to add the code you have tried to your question. Your question will get closed and you will get a negative hit from the community without showing some effort at trying to accomplish the issue you are trying to outline.